# Key up event handler for name attribute assigned to a variable

Tags: jquery, keyup, onkeyup

I want to create a keyup event for every text field on my page. I will eventually have two text fields, both with different name attributes. (The example only has one text field.) Each text field will be created by pressing the button I assigned to it. Questions:

1. Can I create one keyup event for every text field?
2. If I call the keyup handler function before I create the text field, will the keyup function fire on the new text field?
3. I want to use a variable name to assign the keyup handler in my function txtField. This would create a keyup event handler for text fields with the name attribute that matches the value of my fieldName variable. Is this possible? $('[name=fieldName]').keyup(myFunction) doesn't seem to work.
4. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

   ```
   // creates a text field
   function txtField(fieldName, fieldVal){
       var objTxtField = document.createElement("input");
       objTxtField.type = "text";
       objTxtField.name = fieldName;
       objTxtField.value = fieldVal;
       return objTxtField;
   };

   // button fires this function
   // if there is no appended text field, create one and give it focus
   function appendNewField() {
       if ($('[name="appTxtField"]').length === 0) {
           var newTxtField = new txtField("appTxtField", "");
           $("#mainDiv").append(newTxtField);
       };
       $('[name="appTxtField"]').focus();
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you can ( sounds like a campaign line, I know ) you should read about [direct-and-delegated-events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)
2. No, binding events to non-existing element will not fire, **unless** you use jquery's delegation syntax. again [direct-and-delegated-events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)
3. There's nothing wrong with the "txtField" function, you could have used jQuery in a number of ways to achieve that, But there's no reason to do that
   since jQuery abstraction is unnecessary in such a simple operation.

"appendNewField" - Can and should be improved, here's why:

- $('[name="appTxtField"]') is looked up every time the function is called, which is terrible. this is actually looking for the node & constructing the jquery instance of that node on each run ( same goes for "mainDiv" )

What I would do is set a reference in a "appendNewField" outer scope, and use jquery's find method on each call. For example:

```
var mainDiv = $("#mainDiv");

function txtField( fieldName, fieldVal ) { ... };

function appendNewField() {
    if ( mainDiv.find( '[name="appTxtField"]' ).length === 0 ) {
        // utilize the chaining api and use focus directly after the appending.
        $( new txtField("appTxtField", "") ).appendTo( mainDiv ).focus();
    };
}
```

Comment: What are you exactly `.focus()`ing in your example?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sarcasm suits you :) I corrected my example.

Comment: Why the `if ( typeof input !== "undefined" ) {` ?

Comment: Nice and neat. I love that in code. I want to stick on a keyup event handler on that last line as well. I assume I can do that in the normal jQuery way. It should work, correct?

Comment: @KrisHanson Yes it should

Answer (score -1):

```js
var $mainDiv = $("#mainDiv");

// creates a text field
function txtField(name, val){
  return $("<input />", { // Return a new input El
    name: name,           // Assign Properties
    value: val,
    keyup: function(){    // And JS events
      alert("key up! Yey");
    }
  });
}

// button fires this function
// if there is no appended text field, create one and give it focus
function appendNewField() {
  if ($('[name="appTxtField"]').length === 0) {
    var $newField = txtField("appTxtField", ""); // Create it
    $mainDiv.append( $newField );                // Append it
    $newField.focus();                           // Focus it
  }
}

$("button").on("click", appendNewField);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add field</button>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

Or if you like better:

```
function appendNewField() {
  if ($('[name="appTxtField"]').length > 0) return; // Exists already! Exit fn.
  txtField("appTxtField", "").appendTo( $mainDiv ).focus();
}
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fatizi/2/edit?html,js,output)***